# javascript window.open doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I want to use `window.open` to open a window to one of my JSP file. But the browser keeps showing `connecting..`. And even firebug stops working every time I click the text. Neither the `p` nor the `input` tags work, but when I use a `href` to link the JSP it can link to the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Sample JSP Page</title>
<script>
function open(){
    //window.open("hello.jsp","hello","height=700, width=800");
    var x=window.open("hello.jsp","window","status=1,height=700, width=800");
    x.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sample JSP Page</h1>
<p onclick="open()">do not work</p>
<form>
<input type="button" value="new window" onclick="window.open('test-with-utils')"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Might want to rename your open() function as its in the same scope as window.open()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because you have redefined `window.open` when you defined the function open. Use a different function name instead.

Comment: Very clever! I spent some time with a similar problem. Thank you!

Comment: Life saver. Just ran into this :P

Answer (score 6):

Change the name of the function.

Answer (score 5):

The window object is the top level object in JavaScript, and contains in itself several other objects, such as "document", "history" etc.

When you define a variable or a function of your own you really add a new property to the window object. And this will work ( and a little live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/LRjvQ/) ):

```
var foo = "bar";
alert ( window.foo ); // says "bar"
```

In addition if you add this little snippet to your code:

```
window.onerror = function ( msg, url, num ) {
   alert ( "Error: " + msg + "\nURL: " + url + "\nLine: " + num );
   return true;
};
```

you will get this error, when press the button:

```
Error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

This means an endless recursion. It is a side effect - you define a new open function, and when you call `window.open()`, you recursively call your function.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on the reason that you are having problems here, you may want to read a little about javascript Scope ([Very Helpful Blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)). Essentially, consider the following code:

```
<script>
var thisOne=true;
function thatOne() {
alert("whizbang");
}
var theOther={foo:"bar"};

//More code here...
</script>
```

Once you reach the comment, you know you can access those variables and the function directly, like `if (thisOne) {...}`, `element.onclick=thatOne;` or `console.log(theOther.foo)`. However, you can also access them as children of the root object which, in a web browser, is called `window`. So you can do:

```
console.log(window["thisOne"]);
window.thatOne.call(obj, params);
console.log(window.foo.bar);
```

so by defining open() as a function which is not inside another element (which is to say, is inside the root element), you overwrite the window.open() function. When you attempt to call the function later on, you get problems because the open function calls window.open, which calls window.open, which calls window.open...

There's a few ways to get around this -

**Define the onclick handler inline**

To do this, get rid of the whole `<script>..</script>` element then, using whichever element you choose (that supports it) add the onclick attribute:

```
onclick="window.open('hello.jsp','window','status=1,height=700, width=800');"
```

This is a nice and quick method, and it keeps all the logic right there with it's triggering element, but it is not easily extensible and you may find yourself sneered at by some. ("Oh, you use *inline* javascript? how quaint")

**change the method name**

This will take the least effort from you in terms of getting your page working now from what you have (it's also essentially what everyone else has suggested). Just change the name of the open method to something like openANewWindow() or gotoJSP() or anything that doesn't already exist in the root object, making sure to get both where you define it (in the script element) and where you use it (in the onclick attributes).

**Use a closure**

This is almost definitely not what you want in this case, its more complexity than you need for a single function. Just including this as an example of how to get out of the root object, seeing as being in it seems to be the heart of your problem.

You have probably already seen in javascript how to define an object, but you may not know that by defining an object, all you are really doing is adding an object property to the root object. You can use this behavior to your advantage, to give a hierarchical structure to your functions.

For example:

```
<script>
var MyFunctions = (function() {
    function open(){
    var x=window.open("hello.jsp","window","status=1,height=700, width=800");
    x.focus();
    }
    return {open:open};
})();
</script>
```

This creates an anonymous function that is immediately run. Inside the scope of this function, another function, open() is defined, however it is defined within the scope of that anonymous function, not the root object (window). After open() is defined, a reference to it is returned as the value of the object property: open.

The result of all this is that the open property of the MyFunctions object is the function you need. You can then call it with MyFunctions.open() or even window.MyFunctions.open().